# Badges don't even out after Resetting Serial Upvoting

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

As a general rule on SE, badges are not revoked if you get one and then you lose the qualification for that badge. For instance a Necromancer badge is not revoked if the 5th upvoter removes his vote, nor is the Electorate badge revoked if one's question/answer ratio drops below 1/3. The theory is that the next time you earn said badge you won't get an extra one and the totals even out eventually.

A few weeks ago, someone upvoted many of my answers that had 9 votes, granting me many Nice Answer badges. This upvoting was thereby removed by the fraud detection mechanisms SE has in place to protect against sock-puppeting.

Yesterday I received my [22nd Nice Answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/badges/45/nice-answer?userid=759) badge for an upvote to [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/11821/759), however, I currently only [have 17 answers with >10 votes](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/759/double-aa?tab=answers&sort=votes). Why did I get another badge? Maybe when the requirement for the badge is removed by the vote fraud mechanism, the badge counter doesn't notice it?

Comment: so which is your sock-puppet account? `:)`

Comment: @Vram http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/883/hodofhod

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1307/meTAlkative

Comment: @Vram I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/907/1172

Comment: @Vram It was very nice of him/her to help out, wasn't it?

Comment: well her/his [single M.Y answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/14895/1172) was pretty unhelpful; almost insulting to the amazingly amazing question and its (amazing) asker.

Comment: @Vram Odd, then, that he accepted it.

Comment: the accepted answer to that question was given by user **Double AA**. Perhaps you are confusing your accounts?

Comment: @Vram Your accept and unaccept are a matter of public record, as are their timestamps and those of the comments here. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/1307/metalkative?tab=reputation

Comment: lol [many char]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117903/168660) (January 2012):

> note that losing your qualification for a already-earned badge will (usually?) no longer result in your next badge of the same type being withheld.

Comment: I wonder why they did that. The old way made sense to me.

Comment: Based on this answer, I'm tagging the question [meta-tag:status-bydesign].